# Долгий показ сплеша при загрузке данных (iOS 7)

Tags: ios7

Всем привет)
Мы разрабатываем простое контентное приложение под iOS 7, не требующее подключения к инету.
При самом первом запуске после установки билда парсятся данные, этот процес длится 13 секунд.
У нас в команде возникли разногласия по поводу показа сплеша.
С одной стороны, логично эти 13 секунд показывать сплеш, после чего возникнет "готовый" главный экран.
С другой стороны, есть гайдлайны, где сказано что показ сплеша должет быть минимальное время. Боимся, что могут не пропустить на публикацию.

Сейчас билд со вторым вариантом смотрится несколько убого. Сплеш на одну секунду, потом полупустой 
Главный экран с колесиком загрузки данных на 13 секунд.

Будем благодарны, если поделитесь своим опытом.
Пропустят ли на публикацию вариант, где сплеш показывается "так долго" 13 секунд?

Comment: Если эти данные не загружаются с интернета, то какой смысл их парсить при первом запуске? неужели сложно сделать их в таком формате, что бы парсинга как такового не было?

А сплеши - кому они нужны? как по мне - так это просто мусор и указание на то, что автора программы не смогли написать нормально.

Я сам столкнулся с подобным, когда каждый запуск одной android программы занимал от 4 секунд. Небольшой анализ, потом пинание разработчика, которое такое написал и загрузка сократилась до полторы секунды. А когда убрали сплеш (который прикрутили, что бы эти 4 секунды занять), то стало меньше сек

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, использование долгих сплешей вообще нежелательно.
Хотя в играх всегда ставят сплеши с прогресс-баром.

В вашем случае, наверное, подойдет вариант короткого сплеша с последующим показом загрузки.